# CodeIgniter, PHP and reloading the front page when session is destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create a web page where users should be able to register, log in and log out. This all works fine, however, a user is required to press the Sign Out button twice for the page to reload, or at least that's how I see it...

here's some code:

this is the top my page, with the log in / log out options

```
<div id="topmenu">
        <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['check'])) {
        echo ' Welcome, <a href="/index.php/login/">Log In</a> <a href="/index.php/register/">Register</a> ';
        }
        else {
        echo ' Welcome, ' .$_SESSION['name'] .'! <a href="/index.php/login/destroy/">Sign Out</a>'; 
        }

        ?>
</div>
```

Here's what the destroy function does in the login controller

```
public function destroy()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $this->load->view('frontpage');
    }
```

when the Sign Out button is pressed, the frontpage view is loaded, however this bar at the top (the topmenu div) stays the same, and still shows the sign out option, even though the session has been destroyed

Comment: If you just load a view at this point, all internal variables will still be set, I guess. Don’t load a view here, but _redirect_ to the front page, so that a new request is made and CI can figure out from the start that there is no logged-in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. **It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session**, or unset the session cookie.

You have to force a page load, such as a redirect, to get rid of it.

Replace
**$this->load->view('frontpage');**
with
**redirect('frontpage');**
to redirect to a controller called frontpage
OR
**redirect(current_url());**
to redirect to the current page.

You might also get better results using CI's [session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The variables will still be initialized until the next reload, manually unset the check variable with unset($_SESSION['check']) or use a redirect.